# Ionic App Rest Api http.get

Tags: angular, ionic2

In Ionic2 app
Tried with http.get to receive json which worked well when tried with https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10 public api 
but it gives the following error when tried with ios sumulator 
Also it works if i put the json from the my server in the www folder of the project but http.get doesnt work if i put it on the server

console.error: EXCEPTION: Response with status: 0 for URL: null

do you think the method is right

```
this.http.get('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10')
      .map(res => res.json())
.subscribe(data => {
  console.log('before...Hello PeopleService Provider:subscribe');
console.log(data.TripList.Trip);
  this.data1 = data.TripList.Trip;
  resolve(this.data1);
});
```

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#cors

Comment: hi thanks for the comment

Comment: hi thanks for the comment. I have just checked
the server supports only CORS. I have tried with the simulator as mentioned on many places that i CORS problem is only for the ionic serve. But dont know why it is giving problem on the device it self or simulator also.